# Java JPanel and JLabel's

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, grid-layout

I am trying to create 2 sets of JLabels,  one set would include a name and the second set would include values.  The values get pulled from a database and get displayed to the second set of JLabels.

I cant seem how to line up the 2 sets of JLabels so that the set with the names would be on the left side of the panel and the set with the values would be directly to the right. I know my gridlayout has a factor in it I just dont know what it should be.

```
package Frames;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

import Application.Main;

public class AccountFrame extends JPanel implements PropertyChangeListener, ActionListener {

    private static JFrame accountFrame;

    private JLabel firstNameLabel;
    private JLabel lastNameLabel;
    private JLabel dobLabel;
    private JLabel emailLabel;
    private JLabel usernameLabel;
    private JLabel passwordLabel;

    private static String firstNameLabelText = "First Name: ";
    private static String lastNameLabelText = "Last Name: ";
    private static String dobLabelText = "Date Of Birth: ";
    private static String emailLabelText = "Email: ";
    private static String usernameLabelText = "Username: ";
    private static String passwordLabelText = "Password: ";

    private static JButton editButton;
    private static JButton closeButton;

    public AccountFrame() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        firstNameLabel = new JLabel(firstNameLabelText);
        firstNameLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        firstNameLabel.setFont(new Font("Andalus", Font.BOLD, 18));

        lastNameLabel = new JLabel(lastNameLabelText);
        lastNameLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lastNameLabel.setFont(new Font("Andalus", Font.BOLD, 18));

        dobLabel = new JLabel(dobLabelText);
        dobLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        dobLabel.setFont(new Font("Andalus", Font.BOLD, 18));

        emailLabel = new JLabel(emailLabelText);
        emailLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        emailLabel.setFont(new Font("Andalus", Font.BOLD, 18));

        usernameLabel = new JLabel(usernameLabelText);
        usernameLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        usernameLabel.setFont(new Font("Andalus", Font.BOLD, 18));

        passwordLabel = new JLabel(passwordLabelText);
        passwordLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        passwordLabel.setFont(new Font("Andalus", Font.BOLD, 18));

        editButton = new JButton("Edit");
        editButton.setBackground(new Color(129,13,13));
        editButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        editButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        editButton.setFont(new Font("Andalus", Font.BOLD, 18));
        editButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//EDIT ACCOUNT INFORMATION.
            }
        });

        closeButton = new JButton("Close");
        closeButton.setBackground(new Color(129,13,13));
        closeButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        closeButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        closeButton.setFont(new Font("Andalus", Font.BOLD, 18));
        closeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                accountFrame.dispose();
            }
        });

        TitledBorder accountPanelBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE), "Account", TitledBorder.CENTER , TitledBorder.TOP, new Font("Andalus", Font.BOLD, 18));
        accountPanelBorder.setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);

        //this is where the labels need to have values 
        //added on to the string to get values from the current character.
        JPanel accountPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        accountPanel.add(firstNameLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        accountPanel.add(lastNameLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        accountPanel.add(dobLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        accountPanel.add(emailLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        accountPanel.add(usernameLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        accountPanel.add(passwordLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        accountPanel.setBackground(new Color(82,80,80));
        accountPanel.setBorder(accountPanelBorder);
        accountPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,200));

//      JPanel accountValuesPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
//      accountValuesPanel.add(firstNameValue);
//      accountValuesPanel.setBackground(new Color(82,80,80));

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        buttons.add(editButton);
        buttons.add(closeButton);
        buttons.setBackground(new Color(82,80,80));

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
        setBackground(new Color(82,80,80));
        add(accountPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
//      add(accountValuesPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the 
     * event dispatch thread.
     */
    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        accountFrame = new JFrame("OVERRATED");
        accountFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        accountFrame.setBackground(Color.red);
        accountFrame.add(new AccountFrame());
        accountFrame.setVisible(true);
        accountFrame.pack();
        accountFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);   
        accountFrame.setTitle("OVERRATED");
        accountFrame.setResizable(false);
        //startupFrame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon().getImage());
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AccountFrame a = new AccountFrame();
        a.createAndShowGUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggestion : Look into Java Netbeans. It has a drag-and-drop IDE that allows you to just drop elements onto a `JFrame` instead of trying to hard code them. That's how I learned how to work with `JFrame`s and `GroupLayout`s.

Comment: You create a JPanel named accountPanel with a GridLayout, that has only one column. this is not a very good use of a Gridlayout. And then you add your components to it using BorderLayout positioning ?

Comment: Remove all the `BorderLayout.WEST`s, switch it to a `GridLayout(0,2)`, and add alternating names and values. Grid layouts fill up from left to right, and then from top to bottom.

Comment: Placement order depends on the panel's ComponentOrientation property.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, even though your accountPanel layout is gridLayout, you have used it is BorderLayout:

```
JPanel accountPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
accountPanel.add(firstNameLabel, BorderLayout.WEST); // BorderLayout.WEST wrong
```

My suggestion, You should use gridbaglayout for it. GridbagLayout may look difficult to learn but it is actually quite logic.

I have changed your code a little bit.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AccountFrame extends JPanel implements PropertyChangeListener,
        ActionListener {
    private static JFrame accountFrame;
    private JTextField firstNameTextField, lastNameTextField, dobTextField,
            emailTextField, userNameTextField;
    private JPasswordField passwordPasswordField;

    private JLabel firstNameLabel;
    private JLabel lastNameLabel;
    private JLabel dobLabel;
    private JLabel emailLabel;
    private JLabel usernameLabel;
    private JLabel passwordLabel;

    private static String firstNameLabelText = "First Name: ";
    private static String lastNameLabelText = "Last Name: ";
    private static String dobLabelText = "Date Of Birth: ";
    private static String emailLabelText = "Email: ";
    private static String usernameLabelText = "Username: ";
    private static String passwordLabelText = "Password: ";

    private static JButton editButton;
    private static JButton closeButton;

    public AccountFrame() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        firstNameLabel = new JLabel(firstNameLabelText);
        firstNameLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        firstNameLabel.setFont(new Font("Andalus", Font.BOLD, 18));

        lastNameLabel = new JLabel(lastNameLabelText);
        lastNameLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lastNameLabel.setFont(new Font("Andalus", Font.BOLD, 18));

        dobLabel = new JLabel(dobLabelText);
        dobLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        dobLabel.setFont(new Font("Andalus", Font.BOLD, 18));

        emailLabel = new JLabel(emailLabelText);
        emailLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        emailLabel.setFont(new Font("Andalus", Font.BOLD, 18));

        usernameLabel = new JLabel(usernameLabelText);
        usernameLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        usernameLabel.setFont(new Font("Andalus", Font.BOLD, 18));

        passwordLabel = new JLabel(passwordLabelText);
        passwordLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        passwordLabel.setFont(new Font("Andalus", Font.BOLD, 18));

        // lets create JTextFields and a JPasswordField
        firstNameTextField = new JTextField(20);
        lastNameTextField = new JTextField(20);
        dobTextField = new JTextField(20);
        emailTextField = new JTextField(20);
        userNameTextField = new JTextField(20);
        passwordPasswordField = new JPasswordField(20);

        editButton = new JButton("Edit");
        editButton.setBackground(new Color(129, 13, 13));
        editButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        editButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        editButton.setFont(new Font("Andalus", Font.BOLD, 18));
        editButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // EDIT ACCOUNT INFORMATION.
            }
        });

        closeButton = new JButton("Close");
        closeButton.setBackground(new Color(129, 13, 13));
        closeButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        closeButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        closeButton.setFont(new Font("Andalus", Font.BOLD, 18));
        closeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                accountFrame.dispose();
            }
        });

        TitledBorder accountPanelBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE), "Account",
                TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP, new Font("Andalus",
                        Font.BOLD, 18));
        accountPanelBorder.setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);

        // this is where the labels need to have values
        // added on to the string to get values from the current character.
        JPanel accountPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        accountPanel.setBackground(new Color(82, 80, 80));
        accountPanel.setBorder(accountPanelBorder);
        accountPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);

        // lets add labels and textfields

        // 1. row
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        accountPanel.add(firstNameLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        accountPanel.add(firstNameTextField, gbc);

        // 2. row
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        accountPanel.add(lastNameLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        accountPanel.add(lastNameTextField, gbc);

        // 3. row
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        accountPanel.add(dobLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        accountPanel.add(dobTextField, gbc);

        // 4. row
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        accountPanel.add(emailLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        accountPanel.add(emailTextField, gbc);

        // 5. row
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        accountPanel.add(usernameLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        accountPanel.add(userNameTextField, gbc);

        // 6. row
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        accountPanel.add(passwordLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        accountPanel.add(passwordPasswordField, gbc);

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        buttons.add(editButton);
        buttons.add(closeButton);
        buttons.setBackground(new Color(82, 80, 80));

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
        setBackground(new Color(82, 80, 80));
        add(accountPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        // add(accountValuesPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be
     * invoked from the event dispatch thread.
     */
    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        accountFrame = new JFrame("OVERRATED");
        accountFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        accountFrame.setBackground(Color.red);
        accountFrame.add(new AccountFrame());

        accountFrame.pack();
        accountFrame.setTitle("OVERRATED");
        accountFrame.setResizable(false);
        accountFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AccountFrame a = new AccountFrame();
        a.createAndShowGUI();
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that  your `GridLayout` only has 1 column. You need to create your `GridLayout` like this: `new GridLayout(0, 2)`. Below is a small runnable example that lays out pairs of JLabels right next to each other.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Good day");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(400, 250);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
    JLabel left = new JLabel("Foo");
    JLabel right = new JLabel(("Bar"));
    JLabel hello = new JLabel("Hello");
    JLabel world = new JLabel("World");
    panel.add(left);
    panel.add(right);
    panel.add(hello);
    panel.add(world);
    f.add(panel);

    f.setVisible(true);
}
```